# Is it possible to use karma with typescript files and no module loader?

Tags: typescript, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I am trying to create a shared UI component. I would like to utilize the development feedback given by Typescript, but create the transpiled files in such a way that no module loader is required to utilize it.

I have all of that working, but would like to also setup some unit tests around it. This is causing me a lot of problems. My app structure looks like this:

```
karma.conf.js
gulpfile.js
dist/
  component.js
src/
  component.ts
test/
  unit/
    component.spec.ts
```

In the `gulpfile.js` I have two tasks. One that builds the typescript files and places the built `.js` files in `dist/`.

---

If I run my `gulp build` command and then run the `gulp test` command with the following `karma.conf.js` file, all of the tests pass:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: './',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
      'dist/js/pager.js',
      'test/unit/*.spec.ts'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: { },
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

**NOTE**: I am pulling in the build `.js` file explicitly.

---

What I would like to do though, would be to run the tests on the `.ts` file instead so that I can make the `gulp build` task dependent on the `gulp test` task.

I have tried to do so with a `karma.conf.js` file that looks like this:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: './',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'karma-typescript'],
    files: [
      'src/**/*.ts',
      'test/unit/*.spec.ts'
    ],
    exclude: [],
    preprocessors: { 
      "src/**/*.ts": ["karma-typescript"]
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'karma-typescript'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false
  });
};
```

But I continue to get this error: `"ReferenceError: Component is not defined"`

Since the `.js` version above seems to be working, my assumption is that the files are being loaded even in the `.ts` version, but that they aren't being compiled. This confuses me though because the `.spec` files are also typescript files and those are being built just fine.

- I have tried including a reference to the component at the top of the
  spec file like so `/// <reference path="../../src/component.ts" />`.
- I have tried utilizing
  [karma-typescript-preprocessor2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-typescript-preprocessor2).
- I have also tried using `systemjs` to try to treat it as a module,
  but all to no avail.

I'm sure there is something obvious that I'm missing, but can't seem to see it. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Seems like what you want is a separate "compile" task for gulp that will compile the TS files regardless of whether you are going to be building the app or testing it. Then just include that task in both of the other tasks. I'm basing my advice on how I've arranged grunt tasks, so my apologies if they don't make sense for gulp...

Comment: That is definitely one approach that could be taken. I had considered that, but would prefer that the files not get created unless the tests are passing. I have reason to believe that this is possible as well because I've seen other OSS projects that do something similar, but they are utilizing a module loader.